# how do launchSettings.json and appSettings.json work?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

When creating a new .NET Core project Rider generates me a `launchSettings.json`, `appSettings.json` and `appSettings.Development.json` file. .NET Core seems to be able to handle those configurations on its own, there is nothing I have to code myself. None of these files get ignored by version control.

.NET Core is new to me, I only know Node backends yet. In Node I would install the `dotenv` package, create a new `.env` file with the content `PORT=3000`, add `.env` files to my .gitignore and access the port via `process.env.PORT` in my code. Those configuration values only work for me because they are outside from version control.

Comparing the approaches there are some things I didn't understand:

- `.env` files should stay outside from version control, but these files don't? What about sensitive information? Or should I just add them to the .gitignore manually?
- Taken from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv#should-i-have-multiple-env-files) it's clearly recommended to avoid having
  multiple config files.

  > In a twelve-factor app, env vars are granular controls, each fully
  >   orthogonal to other env vars. They are never grouped together as
  >   “environments”, but instead are independently managed for each deploy.
  >   This is a model that scales up smoothly as the app naturally expands
  >   into more deploys over its lifetime.

  So wouldn't it be better to delete the `appSettings.Development.json`
  file and stick with `appSettings.json`?
- The `launchSettings.json` contains information about the application
  configuration (e.g. `"applicationUrl":
  "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",`) and gets picked up
  by version control. What if I want to change the port or other
  settings? And since you know it's a json file I won't be able to add
  placeholders for env variables e.g. `http://{{baseUrl}}:{{port}}`.
  How to deal with that?
- The `launchSettings.json` profiles have a `environmentVariables`
  section with the initial value `"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT":
  "Development"` but what is the purpose of `appSettings.json` then?

I think things are easier than they look but this concept confuses me. Would someone mind explaining it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While I do not know of .env files my answers to the rest are as follow:

When you have appsettings.json and appsettings.development.json and you specify in your ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT that you are running development the settings in appsettings.development.json should overwrite the ones in appsettings.json while the ones not overwritten will be read from appsettings.json.
I however almost always use an appsettings.json containing only {} and then use appsettings.production.json and appsettings.development.json to be explicit about what settings go where.

With regards to security I think the intention is to leave the addition of secrets to the CD system like Octopus deploy or teamcity that will then exchange placeholder secrets for real ones when deploying the solution.

Launchsettings.json only relates to running the project locally without publishing, whether this be via Rider or Visual studio, it tells the system whether or not to launch a browser and what url to find the app on, the ports are just defaults that can be overwritten in code where you then have to match the newly chosen ports in the launchsettings to have debugging work as intended.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So you add appSettings files to .gitignore to keep the configuration for yourself? Because otherwise you would overwritte configurations from other developers

Comment: and the launchSettings.json has nothing to do with the build process later on? just for development purposes for Visual Studio, Rider and `dotnet run`?

Comment: Yes exactly with regards to the lauchSettings.json.

Comment: I would use placeholders in the appSettings.json for things that are secret but allow them in the git repo for things that are not secret, then during publishing I would add the secrets whether through Continuous Delivery systems or manually.

Comment: but how would you add placeholders in the appSettings.json? Because it's just a json file I think

Comment: Yeah that only really works if you do not use local testing, if you do use local testing I would probably add appsettings.development.json and appsettings.production.json to gitignore and then have the appsettings.json with placeholder values so that when you run locally you overwrite the appsettings.json with either appsettings.development.json or appsettings.production.json but when deploying you make sure the appsettings.json being deployed has the right values either manually or through CI/CD.

Comment: I was hoping to find something like this https://hatebin.com/vrqsumzsqw and when running the app in production it would replace the `$` values with values from environment variables

Comment: Yeah, I don't think thats built in, but I would do exactly that and then use Octopus deploy or Azure to change out the values because the deployment system can parse the json and has a secure store for secret data that can then be exchanged at deployment time

Comment: Good idea :) I hope this was helpful